# Docker daemon won't start on centos 6

Tags: linux, docker, centos6

I am trying to install Docker on a Centos 6 machine. I know the kernel is old but I do not have the possibility to update.
I cannot start the daemon, it crashes because of a devicemapper error, the file /dev/loop-control does not exist.

Here is what I have if I start the deamon

```
sudo docker -d -D
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/get                 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/get       
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/history   
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/json      
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /_ping                      
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /events                     
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/json                
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/changes 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/logs  
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /exec/{id:.*}/json          
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/json  
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/attach/ws 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/search              
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/json            
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/export 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/top   
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/stats 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /info                       
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /version                    
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/ps              
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/restart 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/wait 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/attach 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/copy 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/exec 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /build                     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/unpause 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/create         
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/kill 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/pause 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/stop 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/resize 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /commit                    
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/tag      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/resize     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /auth                      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/start      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/push     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/start 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/rename 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/create             
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/load               
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /containers/{name:.*}    
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /images/{name:.*}        
DEBU[0000] Registering OPTIONS,                         
WARN[0000] You are running linux kernel version 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64, which might be unstable running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0. 
DEBU[0000] docker group found. gid: 5020                
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
DEBU[0000] devicemapper: driver version is 4.22.6       
DEBU[0000] Generated prefix: docker-8:1-5384894         
DEBU[0000] Checking for existence of the pool 'docker-8:1-5384894-pool' 
DEBU[0000] Pool doesn't exist. Creating it.             
DEBU[0000] Error retrieving the next available loopback: open /dev/loop-control: no such file or directory 
DEBU[0000] Error retrieving the next available loopback: open /dev/loop-control: no such file or directory 
ERRO[0000] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: Error running DeviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed 
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: Error running DeviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed
```

Here is my system:

```
uname -a

Linux dna 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Dec 10 17:04:11 CST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


docker -v

Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d/1.7.1
```

Could you please help me to setup Docker on this machine?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: This is a unsupported OS. You should avoid using it